# Windows 7 Gadget to display image based on variable read from text file

Tags: html, variables, windows-desktop-gadgets

I'm trying to write a gadget that reads input from a text file. the file contains a number. The gadget needs to read the file and then display the image at a specific location with the number that is read but add ".png" at the end. Example would be "P:/some/location/file_to_read.txt" (contains the number "165") then display the image in the gadget at "P:/some/other/location/165.png"

How do you read a text file and assign the contents as a variable and then use that variable as part of a path to a local file (C:/some/location/$assigned_variable.png) that the gadget will display in JS?

Here is the code I'm using for a temporary solution that pulls the image from a webserver and displays it in the gadget, it works but uses bandwidth...I'd rather use a variable as part of a local path to display

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      //var a=0;
      function init()
      {
            //document.getElementById("status").src="images/head.png";
            document.getElementById("status").src="http://some_web_page/images/head.png?now=" + new Date();
            //document.getElementById("gadgetContent").innerHTML = a;
            //a+=1; //for testing timeout
            setTimeout("init()", 600000);
      }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
<g:background 
    id="background" 
    src="images/headb.png"
    style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:-999;no=repeat;" />
      <img id="status" src="images/head.png"  />
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Er, what actually is your question? I can't see any on this page yet except the one I just asked. You've listed requirements and mentioned something that you can't do. But not actually asked a question. While it seems reasonably clear what you want, many of us have spent far too long guessing only to find the actual question was nothing like we'd imagined. You'll possibly be annoyed by my comment - it's designed to be good for the overall quality of the site. To improve your question, add an example of the text file and your code to process it, along with a direct and closed question. :)

Comment: I assumed anyone answering this question would possibly give me snippets of html/javascript (since that is how a windows gadget is coded, as far as I understand it) to assign a variable from reading a text file and using that variable as part of a path to image which is then display within the gadget. I'm sorry I wasn't clear in that aspect. I did figure it out by using my web server to host the correct image and then in my gadget html I pointed it to that image and made it refresh the image every 10 minutes. I'd post the code but I'm not sure how to format it here..this is my first post

Comment: someone's misinformed you. Here's one from MS that's written in C++: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpdblog/2007/12/19/creating-a-temperature-sensor-gadget-for-windows-sidebar-with-c/  - Again, and forgive my pedantry - you still haven't asked a question. You know, one of those things that ends with the character "**?**". The fact you're trying to extract data from a text file to use when constructing the path to the image actually was clear. There are too many potential imagined questions in your post. Just ask a direct and closed question. I.e "how do I open a file with JS?"

Comment: I think my first line was fairly clear but I'll state it another way. How do you read a text file and assign the contents as a variable and then use that variable as part of a path to a local file (C:/some/location/$assigned_variable.png) that the gadget will display in JS?